# Python requests not returning response

Tags: python, python-requests

1 - The target DOMAIN is https://www.dnb.com/

This website is blocking access to it from many countries around the world including mine (Algeria).

So the known solution is clear **(use a proxy)**, which I did.

2 - Configuring the system proxy in the network configuration, and connecting to the website via (Google Chrome) works, also using Firefox with the proxy settings works fine.

3 - I came to my code to start the job

```
import requests


# 1. Initialize the proxy
proxy = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3128"

# 2. Setting the Headers (I cloned Firefox request headers)
headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Connection": "keep - alive",
        "Accept": "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, image/webp, */*;q = 0.8",
        "Upgrade - Insecure - Requests": "1",
        "Host": "www.dnb.com",
        "DNT": "1"
    }

# 3. URL
URL = "https://www.dnb.com/business-directory/company-profiles.bicicletas_monark_s-a.7ad1f8788ea84850ceef11444c425a52.html"

# 4. Make a get request.
r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, proxies={"https": proxy}) 
# Nothing in return and program keep executing (like infinite loop).
```

**Note:**
I know this keeps on waiting because the default **timeout** is set to **None**, but it is sure that the setup is working, and the requests library must return a response, using the timeout here can be to assess the reliability of the proxy as an example.

So, What the cause for this, it stuck (and I'm also), I'm getting the response and the correct HTML content with (Firefox, Chrome, Postman) with the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and ran it on my local machine. It seems the issue is with proxy. I added a public proxy and it is working. You can confirm it by adding a "timeout" argument to the `requests.get` function to some seconds. Also if the code working properly(even the response is 403) it means there is an issue with the proxy.

Comment: There are two possibilities. 
1. I checked the site with no headers and the site is not responding. So the site will not respond unless we supply proper header values. But here headers are provided. But you can test it with only the "User-agent" header, or clone another browser header. 
2. I checked with a public proxy and the site is responding. So can you double-check the proxy with other methods like the cURL command?
curl https://api.ipify.org --proxy PROXY_IP:PORT